# django application giving 404 error while reading json file python

Tags: python, jquery, django, python-3.x

Here is the code:
**views.py**:

```
@csrf_exempt
def post_list(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {})
@csrf_exempt
def show(request):
    return render(request, 'tt/readjson.html', {})
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list),
    path('test/', views.data_return),
    path('tt/', views.show),
]
```

**readjson.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON("log0.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       console.log(value);
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body> 
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

The output I am getting is `hello` on the screen. But in the console log I see this:

```
jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/tt/log0.json 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8136
jQuery.(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8282
getJSON @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8265
(anonymous) @ (index):5
jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 XHR failed loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tt/log0.json".
```

The `json` file is in the same folder where the html template is kept, that is in the `tt` folder.

Please let me know what might I do to avoid the missing part.

Comment: In your URL patterns you have paths `''`, `'test/'` and `tt/'` which correspond to URLs `/`, `/test/` and `/tt/`. You don't have a path for `/tt/log0.json`, so you get a 404. You could add a view to handle that URL, or perhaps `log0.json` belongs in your [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/).

Comment: @Alasdair guess I need to check it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no good putting your JSON into the same folder as the template. Templates aren't accessible via HTTP requests; they are rendered by views served at URLs.

You should put your JSON into a static directory and access it via STATIC_URL; alternatively you could write a view to serve it like you have for your other templates, but there doesn't seem to be any point doing that.

Comment: Yes it worked. I have got this suggestion @Alasdair. It helped a lot.